# Renaming files based on Dataframe content with Python and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read a `xlsx` file, compare all the reference numbers from a column to files inside a folder and if they correspond, rename them to an email associate with the reference number.

**Excel File** has fields such as:

```
 Reference     EmailAddress
   1123        bob.smith@yahoo.com
   1233        john.drako@gmail.com
   1334        samuel.manuel@yahoo.com
   ...         .....
```

My folder `applicants` just contains **doc** files named as the **Reference** column:

[image]

How can I compare the contents of the `applicantsCVs` folder, to the **Reference** field inside my excel file and if it matches, rename all of the files as the corresponding email address ?

Here is What I've tried so far:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

dfOne = pd.read_excel('Book2.xlsx', na_values=['NA'], usecols = "A:D")
references = dfOne['Reference']

emailAddress = dfOne['EmailAddress']

cleanedEmailList = [x for x in emailAddress if str(x) != 'nan']

print(cleanedEmailList)
excelArray = []
filesArray = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("applicantCVs"):
    for filename in files:
        print(filename) #Original file name with type 1233.doc
        reworkedFile = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
        filesArray.append(reworkedFile)

for entry in references:
    excelArray.append(str(entry))

for i in excelArray:
    if i in filesArray:
        print(i, "corresponds to the file names")
```

I compare the reference names to the folder contents and print it out if it's the same:

```
 for i in excelArray:
        if i in filesArray:
            print(i, "corresponds to the file names")
```

I've tried to rename it with `os.rename(filename, cleanedEmailList )` but it didn't work because `cleanedEmailList` is an array of emails.

How can I match and rename the files?

**Update:**

```
from os.path import dirname
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
import os

dfOne = pd.read_excel('Book2.xlsx', na_values=['NA'], usecols = "A:D")

emailAddress = dfOne['EmailAddress']
reference = dfOne['Reference'] = dfOne.references.astype(str)

references = dict(dfOne.dropna(subset=[reference, "EmailAddress"]).set_index(reference)["EmailAddress"])
print(references)
files = Path("applicantCVs").glob("*")

for file in files:
    new_name = references.get(file.stem, file.stem)
    file.rename(file.with_name(f"{new_name}{file.suffix}"))
```

Comment: what do you want to rename the files to?

Comment: You want to match the contents of Word Document or just want to match the `Reference` of excel file with name of the word document ?

Comment: @MaartenFabré I want to rename the files to the **email address** column inside the CSV

Answer (score 3):

based on sample data:

```
Reference     EmailAddress
   1123        bob.smith@yahoo.com
   1233        john.drako@gmail.com
   nan         jane.smith#example.com
   1334        samuel.manuel@yahoo.com
```

First you assemble a `dict` with the set of references as keys and the new names as values:

```
references = dict(df.dropna(subset=["Reference","EmailAddress"]).set_index("Reference")["EmailAddress"])
```

> ```
> {'1123': 'bob.smith@yahoo.com',
>  '1233': 'john.drako@gmail.com',
>  '1334': 'samuel.manuel@yahoo.com'}
> ```

Note that the references are `str`s here. If they aren't in your original database, you can use `astype(str)`

Then you use `pathlib.Path` to look for all the files in the data directory:

```
files = Path("../data/renames").glob("*")
```

> ```
> [WindowsPath('../data/renames/1123.docx'),
>  WindowsPath('../data/renames/1156.pptx'),
>  WindowsPath('../data/renames/1233.txt')]
> ```

The renaming can be made very simple:

```
for file in files:
    new_name = references.get(file.stem, file.stem )
    file.rename(file.with_name(f"{new_name}{file.suffix}"))
```

The `references.get` asks for the new filename, and if it doesn't find it, use the original stem.

> ```
> [WindowsPath('../data/renames/1156.pptx'),
>  WindowsPath('../data/renames/bob.smith@yahoo.com.docx'),
>  WindowsPath('../data/renames/john.drako@gmail.com.txt')]
> ```

Comment: it's hard for me to integrated your changes into my script. Sorry for the late response.

Comment: The problem that I am having with this code is that whenever I run it, I Don't rename the files to the appropriate **EmailAddress** but the files still remain the same.

Comment: It worked for the test files I used. You can start diagnosing your problem at the top, and check which part fails. Are the keys in `references` correct and `str`s, is `files` really a `generator` with all the files, etc..

Comment: I found the problem, it's that `new_name` consists only of the reference numbers. The `str`s and `files` are correct. The problem is that ` file.rename(file.with_name(f"{new_name}{file.suffix}"))` passes `new_name` as the reft number not the email.

Comment: `references.get(file.stem, file.stem)` queries the `references` dict for the stem of the file. (`"1123"` in my example). If it is not in the dict, it returns the original stem. So if `new_name` is still the id, and not the corresponding email address, then the id does not appear in the `references` dict, or they are not of the correct type (int instead of str)

Comment: oh alright, thanks for the explanation! How can I change it to `astype(str)`? I've tried with `df['EmailAddress'] = df.emailAddress.astype(str)` but it gave me an error.

Comment: the email adress will be a string already normall, it's the Reference you need to convert to string

Comment: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'references'` is what I get whenever I try to do that. Btw my data is stored inside an `excel` file not a database..

Comment: Normally I don't use the `df.column_name` syntax, but `df["column_name"]`. Also, capitalization is important

Comment: I've updated my question with the new code if you want to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding the "email associate" (your new name i guess?) into an dictionary, where the keys are your reference numbers?
This could look something like:

```
cor_dict = {}

for i in excelArray:
        if i in filesArray:
            cor_dict[i] =dfOne['EmailAddress'].at[dfOne.Reference == i]


for entry in cor_dict.items():
    path = 'path to file...'
    filename = str(entry[0])+'.doc'
    new_filename =  str(entry[1]).replace('@','_') + '_.doc'

    filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
    new_filepath = os.path.join(path,new_filename)

    os.rename(filename, new_filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it directly in your dataframe using `df.apply()`:

```
import glob
import os.path

#Filter out null addresses
df = df.dropna(subset=['EmailAddress']) 

#Add a column to check if file exists
df2['Existing_file'] = df2.apply(lambda row: glob.glob("applicantsCVs/{}.*".format(row['Reference'])), axis=1)

df2.apply(lambda row: os.rename(row.Existing_file[0], 'applicantsCVs/{}.{}'.format( row.EmailAddress, row.Existing_file[0].split('.')[-1])) if len(row.Existing_file) else None, axis = 1)
print(df2.Existing_file.map(len), "existing files renamed")
```

**EDIT** :
works now with any extension (`.doc`, `.docx`) by using [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) module

Comment: You can use pd.dropna(subset='EmailAdress') to filter the empty addresses

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach using a simple iteration.

**Ex:**

```
import os

#Sample Data#
#dfOne = pd.DataFrame({'Reference': [1123, 1233, 1334, 4444, 5555],'EmailAddress': ["bob.smith@yahoo.com", "john.drako@gmail.com", "samuel.manuel@yahoo.com", np.nan, "samuel.manuel@yahoo.com"]})
dfOne = pd.read_excel('Book2.xlsx', na_values=['NA'], usecols = "A:D")
dfOne.dropna(inplace=True)  #Drop rows with NaN

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("applicantsCVs"):
    for file in files:
        file_name, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
        email = dfOne[dfOne['Reference'].astype(str).str.contains(file_name)]["EmailAddress"]
        if email.values:
            os.rename(os.path.join(root, file), os.path.join(root, email.values[0]+ext))
```

---

Or if you have only `.docx` file to rename

```
import os

dfOne = pd.read_excel('Book2.xlsx', na_values=['NA'], usecols = "A:D")

dfOne["Reference"] = dfOne["Reference"].astype(str)
dfOne.dropna(inplace=True)  #Drop rows with NaN
ext = ".docx"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("applicantsCVs"):
    files = r"\b" + "|".join(os.path.splitext(i)[0] for i in files) + r"\b"
    for email, ref in dfOne[dfOne['Reference'].astype(str).str.contains(files, regex=True)].values:
        os.rename(os.path.join(root, ref+ext), os.path.join(root, email+ext))
```

Answer (score 0):

Let consider our sample data in excel sheet is following:

```
Reference   EmailAddress
1123    bob.smith@yahoo.com
1233    john.drako@gmail.com
1334    samuel.manuel@yahoo.com
nan     python@gmail.com
```

There are following steps involved to solve this problem.

## Step 1

import the data properly from excel sheet `"my.xlsx"`. Here I am using the sample data

```
import pandas as pd
import os
#import data from excel sheet and drop rows with nan 
df = pd.read_excel('my.xlsx').dropna()
#check the head of data if the data is in desirable format
df.head()
```

You will see that the data type in the references are in float type here

[image]

## Step 2

Change the data type in the reference column to integer and then into string

```
df['Reference']=df.Reference.astype(int, inplace=True)
df = df.astype(str,inplace=True)
df.head()
```

Now the data is in desirable format

[image]

## Step 3

Renaming the files in the desired folder. Zip the lists of 'Reference' and 'EmailAddress' to use in for loop.

```
#absolute path to folder. I consider you have the folder "application cv" in the home directory
path_to_files='/home/applicant cv/'
for ref,email in zip(list(df['Reference']),list(df['EmailAddress'])):
    try: 
        os.rename(path_to_files+ref+'.doc',path_to_files+email+'.doc')
    except:
        print ("File name doesn't exist in the list, I am leaving it as it is")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** import the data from excel sheet `"Book1.xlsx"`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel (r'path of your file here\Book1.xlsx')        
print (df)
```

**Step 2:** Choose path that your `".docx"` files are in and store their names.
Get only relevent part of filename to compare.

```
mypath = r'path of docx files\doc files'
from os import listdir,rename
from os.path import isfile, join
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
#print(onlyfiles)
currentfilename=onlyfiles[0].split(".")[0]
```

[This is how I stored the files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvQFQ.png)

**Step 3:** Run loop to check if name matches with the Reference. And just use `rename(src,dest)` function from `os`

```
for i in range(3):
    #print(currentfilename,df['ref'][i])
    if str(currentfilename)==str(df['Reference'][i]):
        corrosponding_email=df['EmailAddress'][i]
        #print(mypath+"\\"+corrosponding_email)
rename(mypath+"\\"+str(currentfilename)+".docx",mypath+"\\"+corrosponding_email+".docx")
```

checkout the code with example:[https://github.com/Vineet-Dhaimodker](https://github.com/Vineet-Dhaimodker/stack-overflow-issue-solutions/tree/master/01)